# replace is either working correctly, partial replacing, or not replacing at all. How do I get a consistent result

Tags: powershell, replace

I have tried using .replace and -replace in my code but I cannot get a consistent result with it.  I'm trying to remove "\cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software Installs\2. Network Printers\00000 installRicoh" from the path of a bunch of objects in the array $oldprintersripts  Here is the code:

```
$oldprintersripts = @('\\cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software Installs\2. Network Printers\PleasantVille\WIB\YouthCorp','\\cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software Installs\2. Network Printers\00000 installRicoh\PleasantVille\WIB\HP401dn','\\cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software Installs\2. Network Printers\00000 installRicoh\Northfield X\Stillwater\3rd Flr IDRC','\\cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software Installs\2. Network Printers\00000 installRicoh\00000 installRicoh\Drexel\Support Work Front Office')
$printerfilepath = ""
Foreach($x in $oldprintersripts){
$x.Path
$printerfilepath = $x.path.Replace("\\cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software Installs\2. Network Printers\00000 installRicoh\","")#[regex]::Escape('\\cobsvit2\Infotech\9. Scripts\New printer install Script\Printers\'))
$printerfilepath
"`n"
```

Here is the output I'm getting:

> \cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software Installs\2. Network
> Printers\PleasantVille\WIB\YouthCorp \cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software
> Installs\2. Network Printers\PleasantVille\WIB\YouthCorp
>
> \cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software Installs\2. Network Printers\00000
> installRicoh\PleasantVille\WIB\HP401dn PleasantVille\WIB\HP401dn
>
> \cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software Installs\2. Network Printers\00000
> installRicoh\Northfield X\Stillwater\3rd Flr IDRC Northfield
> X\Stillwater\3rd Flr IDRC
>
> \cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software Installs\2. Network Printers\00000
> installRicoh\00000 installRicoh\Drexel\Support Work Front Office 00000
> installRicoh\Drexel\Support Work Front Office

Both .replace("\cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software Installs\2. Network Printers\00000 installRicoh","") and -replace([regex]::Escape('\cobsvit2\Infotech\9. Scripts\New printer install Script\Printers')) outputs are all over the place.  Some outputs are correct, some are partially removed, and others nothing is happening. How do I get a consistent result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the same output with the code you provided. It resulted in errors at "$x.Path"

Perhaps this might work for you. From what I could tell this may be the output you're looking for.

```
$oldprintersripts = @(
    '\\cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software Installs\2. Network Printers\PleasantVille\WIB\YouthCorp',
    '\\cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software Installs\2. Network Printers\00000 installRicoh\PleasantVille\WIB\HP401dn',
    '\\cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software Installs\2. Network Printers\00000 installRicoh\Northfield X\Stillwater\3rd Flr IDRC',
    '\\cobsvit2\Infotech\4. Software Installs\2. Network Printers\00000 installRicoh\00000 installRicoh\Drexel\Support Work Front Office'
    )
$printerfilepath = ""
Foreach($x in $oldprintersripts){
    #Replaces from beginning of path to "Network Printers\", then replaces new beginning to "installRicoh\", then replaces beginning with your new path" 
    $printerfilepath = $x -replace "^.*Network\sPrinters\\" -replace "^.*installRicoh\\" -replace "^","\\cobsvit2\Infotech\9. Scripts\New printer install Script\Printers\"
    $printerfilepath
"`n"
}
```

Output ($printerfilepath):

```
\\cobsvit2\Infotech\9. Scripts\New printer install Script\Printers\PleasantVille\WIB\YouthCorp


\\cobsvit2\Infotech\9. Scripts\New printer install Script\Printers\PleasantVille\WIB\HP401dn


\\cobsvit2\Infotech\9. Scripts\New printer install Script\Printers\Northfield X\Stillwater\3rd Flr IDRC


\\cobsvit2\Infotech\9. Scripts\New printer install Script\Printers\Drexel\Support Work Front Office
```

If the above regex fails on additional filepaths not shown in your sample set, you could try [Regular Expressions 101](https://regex101.com/) site for testing/debugging.

Comment: Thanks that worked.  My next question is why did my original script only work for somethings and not others?